# How to check a specific artifact's existence in mavenLocal repository （i.e. .m2 repo) , in Android Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, artifact

As titled, is there any able gradle api or maven api to check this? I have read other similar questions, but there is no complete answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use mavenLocal, you can add following in your gradle file

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}
```

the following answer might give you some idea around it, the solution is for remote artifact downloaded in mavenLocal, but i think you can do small tweaks for your purpose.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4809634/4828650

You can search the artifact available on mavencentral on the following link.
https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central

And for most of google's artifacts you can find in following link,many of the artifact of google are there on above link.

https://maven.google.com/web/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Nobody, but I just want to check whether an artifact is exit in my local maven repo. Finally , I choose Java File api : boolean exited = new  File (./m2/repository/foo/bar/1.0.0/demo.jar).exit()